# Как перекинуть файл с помощью pscp с win на виртуальную машину linux

Tags: linux, сеть

[image: Интерфейсы на ВМ]

Что именно мне нужно указать при использовании pscp. Я выполняю такую команду: pscp  root@127.0.0.1:/root/, но выводит connection refused. Сеть на ВМ организована по принципу NAT, 1 из интерфейсов подключен к локальной сети. Подключение по ssh работает. Подскажите, где я ошибся, т.к. я, наверное, не совсем понял что и как работает.

Comment: Напишите, точную команду, которой вы проверяете что `Подключение по ssh работает`.

Comment: И еще. Если используется NAT для обоих интерфейсов, то VM не может быть доступна извне. Как все таки сконфигурированы сетевые интерфейсы в VM?

Comment: Я пробросил порт в ВМ, благодаря чему и могу подключиться по ssh извне, просто проблема в том, что что-то, наверное, не так с ssh-конфигом / файерволом, хотя последний, вроде бы, настроен нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы собираетесь перекинуть файл с Windows на на linux - надо пользоваться scp-клиентом под Windows. Если хотите в обратном порядке - надо ставить OpenSSH-Server под Windows[Установка OpenSSH для Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse)

Если у Вас основной хост Windows с виртульным сервером, на котором крутится виртуалка с linux - без проблем настраивается доступ к linux машинке за NAT. Внешнего доступа с другого хоста не будет.

Очень удобный клиент scp под Windows WinSCP. Есть portable-версия. Или использовать нативный OpenSSH.Client Windows 10.

Вот пример на базе VMware Workstation Player под Windows.
Виртуалка с Linux и OpenSSH-server. По умолчанию доступ по root закрыт !!!
[image: Стандартная настройка]

[image: Доступна во внутренней сети]

[image: Windows WinSCP клиент]

строка scp://user@192.168.147.128/home/user/ не будет работать в нативном OpenSSH.Client Windows 10 [Пример](https://winitpro.ru/index.php/2020/01/22/vstroennyj-ssh-klient-windows/)

Answer (score -2):

Доступ root к ssh серверу обычно по умолчанию заблокирован.
Поставьте себе WinSCP https://winscp.net/eng/docs/lang:ru